# dynamic update to data for dygraph in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

Hello I was wondering is it possible to replicate this (http://dygraphs.com/tests/dynamic-update.html) in R shiny?

I am looking at the documentation for the dygraph package (https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/index.html) and cannot see anything associated with it updates to data that don't fully re-draw the graph, perhaps some sort of proxy is required?

Comment: Your graph should re-render in response to updates to your input object.

Comment: one of many examples that could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480302/creating-a-shiny-app-with-real-time-data

Comment: Another example: https://plot.ly/r/streaming/

Comment: Any update on this question? I am also looking for a solution for it.