# RStudio : Refresh viewer output at runtime when plotting graphs

Tags: r, rstudio, dygraphs

I am running the following loop in a function:

```
for (i in 1:400) {
 m<-update_values() # Updates values in the dataframe   
 dygraph(m[,1:4]) %>%
    dyCandlestick() %>%
      dyRangeSelector()
 Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

The problem is that RStudio's viewer is locked while the function runs and the plot is not even displayed when the function returns (I can only manually plot the collected data afterwards). I would want the plot to be displayed at each step. Any idea how to achieve this?

Edit: This function monitors sensors in real time, so it needs to plot at runtime.

Comment: You could use the `rstudioapi` package to update the viewer inside your function or loop.

Comment: Hi Kevin. I have already checked the rstudioapi, but could not find a way to update the viewer. How would you proceed?

Comment: To be honest, I would likely take a very different approach to your problem. Prepare a data frame that contains the values of all your plots and then `lapply` or `purrr::map` the results. They could then be displayed in sequence on demand.

Comment: Actually, I need the function to run and plot while running, because this function is used to monitor the progress of some sensors in real time. Therefore, I cannot afford to wait until the function returns to get the outputs.

Comment: If you are looking for something similar to [this](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update) then I recommend either a shiny app or widget using an approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480302/creating-a-shiny-app-with-real-time-data) or *javascript* directly with `shinyjs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dygraph` function uses an HTML widget, so the result needs to be printed to appear in the viewer.  Just add `%>% print()` at the end and the output should appear, i.e.

```
for (i in 1:400) {
  m<-update_values() # Updates values in the dataframe   
  dygraph(m[,1:4]) %>%
    dyCandlestick() %>%
      dyRangeSelector() %>%
        print()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

However, a disadvantage of this approach is that you'll end up with 400 pages in the viewer.  As far as I know there's no way to say to replace the current view, you can just add new ones.  Maybe `rstudioapi` has a "Delete viewer page" function, but I don't see it.

Comment: Thanks! This is the most straightforward answer.